# Unique 4 character codes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

For reasons i won't go into, i need to create unique IDs with 4 characters all starting with A. so for instance;

AAAA
AAAB
AAAC

and so on. I've looked at the uniqid() function but it seems that will only create a numeric value. This code doesn't need to be random, it can go in sequence so i could use the following to iterate through.

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z');

foreach ($letters as $one) {
  foreach ($letters as $two) {
    foreach ($letters as $three) {
      foreach ($letters as $four) {
        echo "$one$two$three$four";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now how could i store the state of this loop in a database as not all records would be create at the same time?

Comment: you don't even need to store it. just `select max(code) from yourtable` -- that'll fetch the latest one. they have a natural order.

Comment: Use an auto_increment field and then simply encode that number as as your alpha ID. Trying to implement your own sequence generator is neither easy nor fun.

Comment: Are you asking how to create the 4 char code, or how to store it? Or how to retrieve it?

Comment: This would be a lot less messy with a little recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is essentially a base 26 number, using just letters as the digits. So you can store an incrementing number in the database, then convert this to the corresponding code.

After converting to base 26, you shift all the digits: `0` becomes `A`, `1` becomes `B`, `A` becomes `K`, etc.

```
function num_to_code($num) {
    $base26 = str_split(str_pad(strtoupper(base_convert($num, 10, 26)), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
    $result = "";
    foreach ($base26 as $char) {
        $result .= is_numeric($char) ? chr(ord('A') + $char) : chr(ord($char) + 10);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/40AnHx)

Comment: but wouldnt converting base10 of 1000 = 1CC?

Comment: @Nathan That's why it shifts everything to letters.

Comment: `chr(ord($char) - 22)` will get you upper-case letters rather than lower-case

Comment: @Sammitch I added `strtoupper()` to fix that problem.

Comment: @Barmar oh I guess we're just *giving* CPU cycles away today. :P

Comment: Have you checked the other answer? His version is `O($num)`.

Comment: dont drag me into anything, i never claimed mine was a good idea

Comment: BRB, writing a Medium post titled: StackOverflow's Culture of Technical Relativism.

Comment: make sure you talk about the PHP tag being the bottom of the bucket

Comment: thanks for the answer, it makes sense in my tiny brain. I'll work on doing a reverse function of code_to_num

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the best idea but if you have an auto-incremented id in the database you could always:

```
$autoinc = 36; // lets say its the 36th record
$alpha_id = "AAAA";
for($i=0; $i < $autoinc; $i++) {
    $alpha_id++;
}
var_dump($alpha_id); // AABK
```

If they have to start with A, and are only 4 characters long you only get about 17.5k records before you run out though.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar's answer is plenty good, but I noticed a distinct lack of *math* being done. So I've dug up some old code I wrote for a situation like this:

```
function arb_encode($num, $basestr) {
    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $rep = '';
    while($num > 0) {
        $rem = $num % $base;
        $rep = $basestr[$rem] . $rep;
        $num = ($num - $rem) / $base;
    }
    return $rep;
}

function arb_decode($num, $basestr) {
    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $dec = 0;
    $num_arr = str_split((string)$num);
    $cnt = strlen($num);
    for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($basestr, $num_arr[$i]);
        if( $pos === false ) {
            Throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown character %s at offset %d', $num_arr[$i], $i));
        }
        $dec = ($dec * $base) + $pos;
    }
    return $dec;
}

$alpha = implode('', range('A', 'Z'));
var_dump(
    str_pad( arb_encode(1234, $alpha), 4, 'A', STR_PAD_LEFT),
    arb_decode('BUTT', $alpha)
);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "ABVM"
int(31609)
```

Comment: hehe, he said "butt" :P